# Drawing graph of variance using R

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, variance, binomial-distribution, graphical-model

I am a self -learner and try to learn statistics with R ,but i encounter with a problem i could not handle it such that

I want to  produce a graph of the variance of a binomial distribution with a given $n=14$ as
a function of the success probability where binomial distribution is given as $b(x,n,0.25)$

I know that formula of variance of binomial distribution is $np(1-p)$ . However , when i apply it to the question , i obtained $14 \times (0.25) \times (0.75) =\frac{13}{4}$

This is a contant and i think a graph cannot be produced . Can you help me to draw the graph of its variance ? By the way , i know only using $R$ language , so if you help me over $R$ , i will be happy. Thanks for any helps

Comment: https://rpubs.com/mpfoley73/458411

Comment: @EB3112 there is not any code to graph variance in given link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you keep the parameters $n$ and $p$ of the distribution fixed at $n=14$ and $p=\frac 1 4$ then of course the variance will also be constant. You have to **vary** on of the parameters. I assume that you want $p$  to vary. Then you can plot this variance using the `curve` function in R. See also its help page (`?curve`) for more details.

```r
curve(14 * x * (1 - x), from = 0, to = 1)
```